Problem making a quote appear in the memory windows in Visual Studio
.386
.model flat

.data
quote byte "Machines do feel",0
message byte SIZEOF quote DUP(0),0

.code
start proc
      mov esi,0
      mov ecx,SIZEOF quote

LP:
      mov al, quote[esi]  ;get a character from quote
      mov message[esi],al ;store in the message
      inc esi
      loop LP

      ret
start endp
end   start

I used this code in an .ASM file in assembly. It was on an x86 platform, the entry point was start, and the breakpoint was on ret. The code was supposed to show the quote "Machines do feel" twice in one of the 4 memory windows that you can see when you use a debugger, and yet for some reason it did not appear even though the online course I learn from clearly displays otherwise. Because of that, for now I'm resorting to ask for help online. I hope I explained myself well and there's a mistake I can learn from.
I tried to make the message "Machines do feel" appear twice in the memory windows when the program is debugged.

This needs more info.  What debugger are you using? How do you have the memory windows set up - what ranges of addresses are they displaying, and how are you ensuring that they include the addresses of your two strings?

Works on my PC, if I set a breakpoint on ret and type &message into the address box of a memory window, I see the text there. And if I type &quote then I see the original there, and the copy right after it, no problem.
